# Jquery keypress event does not add character to textbox

Tags: angularjs, jquery

Through code, I would like to manually enter some characters to a input using JQuery.

I am using this:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
e.which = 97; 
$("input").trigger(e);
```

I also have a eventhandler attached to the input that is logging the triggered event correctly along with the keyCode etc.

In other words the event does seem to be fired through code and get handled too. However, the value on the input is still empty. The character is not added there. Not sure what is going on.

EDIT: I am creating automated tests that is supposed to trigger a `keypress` on my `autocomplete` compoment. the App is written using `AngularJS`. It is not possible to put all the code and html on JSFiddle etc. I have isolated this to be a `Jquery` problem as stated above.

I know I can use `val()` directly but that will not trigger the `keypress` events necessary for the plugin to work

Comment: Having a hard time understanding why you are going about it in this manner. Can you provide your HTML or further explanation? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you trying to test the handler itself? Why not perform the test directly on the handler?

Comment: probably to unit test you should try this https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/tests/jquery.simulate.js

Comment: I am doing End to End functional tests of the whole page. This involves populating the form using code. One of the components of the form is a autocomplete custom component. I need to send keypress to that input so that AutoComplete will work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried:

```
$("input").keypress(function(){
 $(this).prop('value', 'your value')
```

});

Comment: why do I have to manually use val()? I am expecting keypress to do that already.

Comment: Why should keypress have something to do with the element's value?

Comment: it is not possible to fire the default browser keypress event as well as you cannot trigger default click on a link . This answer is the best option that you can have.

Comment: Is he trying to get a window keypress? I don't understand what he wants to do. $(window).keypress()